# segs_out vs data_segs_out and segs_in vs data_segs_out

Tags: sockets

Confused about the output of `ss -tiem`. The main page shows `segs_out: segments sent out` and `segs_in: segments received`. What do `data_segs_out` and `data_segs_in` denote?

```
        s.segs_out = info->tcpi_segs_out;
        s.segs_in = info->tcpi_segs_in;
        s.data_segs_out = info->tcpi_data_segs_out;
        s.data_segs_in = info->tcpi_data_segs_in;
```

I am trying to get an idea of no. packages sent and received from this `ss` output.

```
["'",
 '0',
 '0',
 '10.120.238.136:58698',
 '192.168.144.240:443',
 'users:(("do_random_gets.",pid=15692,fd=6))',
 'uid:1000',
 'ino:15472236',
 'sk:532',
 '<->',
 'ts',
 'sack',
 'cubic',
 'wscale:8,7',
 'rto:232',
 'rtt:29.86/17.82',
 'ato:40',
 'mss:1428',
 'pmtu:1500',
 'rcvmss:1448',
 'advmss:1448',
 'cwnd:10',
 'bytes_acked:908',
 'bytes_received:38631032',
 'segs_out:10317', // <--
 'segs_in:26692', // <--
 'data_segs_out:3', // <--
 'data_segs_in:26690', // <-- 
 'send',
 '3.8Mbps',
 'lastsnd:3928',
 'lastack:8',
 'pacing_rate',
 '7.7Mbps',
 'delivery_rate',
 '472.7Kbps',
 'app_limited',
 'busy:124ms',
 'rcv_rtt:106.739',
 'rcv_space:2202045',
 'rcv_ssthresh:3144832',
 'minrtt:23.148',
 "'"]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to [RFC4898: TCP Extended Statistics MIB](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4898.txt):

- `s.segs_out`: The total number of segments sent.
- `s.segs_in`: The total number of segments received.
- `s.data_segs_out`: The number of segments sent containing a positive length data segment.
- `s.data_segs_in`: The number of segments received containing a positive length data segment.

The connection between the output of [ss(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ss.8.html) and the variables in RFC4898 can be uncovered by:

1. reading the code in [ss.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/tree/misc/ss.c), see `tcp_show_info()` where a `tcp_info` struct is populated and `tcp_stats_print()` that prints the data,
2. seeing that in [tcp.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h) there is the definition of `tcp_info` with pointers to RFC4898 for some of the variables, e.g., `tcpi_segs_out` has `/* RFC4898 tcpEStatsPerfSegsOut */` as a comment next to it, and
3. checking the "Description" fields in RFC4898 for the variables of interest

In [tcp.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h) the comments next to `tcpi_data_segs_in` and `tcpi_data_segs_out` read `/* RFC4898 tcpEStatsDataSegsIn */` and `/* RFC4898 tcpEStatsDataSegsOut */`, respectively. However, in RFC4898, there are no `tcpEStatsDataSegsIn` and `tcpEStatsDataSegsOut`, but `tcpEStatsPerfDataSegsIn` and `tcpEStatsPerfDataSegsOut`.